# Why float operation return integer numbers in C# PointF?

Tags: c#, double, point

I have the following statement which uses all flat data type.

```
ScaledCordinates.BottomRight = new PointF(((float)ScaleBottomRight.X * (float)Scale), ((float)ScaleBottomRight.Y * (float)Scale));
```

The values assigned to `"ScaleBottomRight.X" is 2.36523485` and `"ScaleBottomRight.Y" is 2.38020468`.
`"Scale" = 66.80098`.

I don't understand why `"ScaledCordinates.BottomRight"` is giving me `{X = 158 Y = 159}` in my app.
Why is the float operation returns integer values? It's even frustrating some times output is an integer and some times float. I did all sorts of conversions between double and float but the same result. What's the best way to fix these issues? The output should be a "float" data type.

Comment: Can show show us "which times" the output is an integer vs a float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
2.36523485 * 66.80098 = 158.000005910153
```

and

```
2.38020468 * 66.80098 = 159.0000052245864
```

They both have too small fractional part to fit in float precision, which is ~6-9 digits according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). The result of multiplication is still `float` (i.e. `System.Single`) though:

```
Console.WriteLine((2.36523485f * 66.80098f)); // prints "158"
Console.WriteLine((2.36523485f * 66.80098f).GetType()) // prints "System.Single"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that whatever Type `ScaledCordinates.BottomRight` is, its `X` and `Y` properties (of fields) are of Type `int`.

For example, it might be of Type [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point), whose X and Y are `int`s: [X docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point.x). [Y docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point.y).

You can change it to a different Type. But as long as they are `int`s - you can't keep the floating point information.